# Flooring a random exponential value for a cookie key

Tags: javascript, string, random, pow, floor

Is it possible to get string with length of 17 by using such code?
We're saving cookie in a client's browser and then get it from this browser.

```
function getPartnerVisitorId() {
    var pvid = cookies.get('pvid') || Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 15)).toString();
    cookies.setOnRoot('pvid', pvid, 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    return pvid;
};
```

We think that "pvid" should be maximum of 16 digits length, but sometimes (about 5% of cookies) we get 17 digits length of this cookie.

Also we've noticed that all of strange cookies are even numbers and most of them (75%) had zero as the last digit

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you're dealing with has to do the nature of IEEE 754 floating point numbers - the type used to hold `Number` in JavaScript, `double` in Java and C, etc. These numbers are stored in a sort of scientific notation, in the form of

`[+/-] 1.[some value] * 2^[some other value]`.

This results in you getting about 15 significant decimal digits that are especially adept at expressing powers of 2.

By multiplying `Math.random()` by `Math.pow(10,15)`, you are encountering two problems with this scheme:

- You are running out of digits, hence truncating the last few at the bottom (hence why your numbers are always even)
- You are trying to represent a power of 10, which it cannot always do accurately (hence why you are sometimes getting 17-digit keys).

To fix these problems and get the constant-length random keys you want, do two things:

- Multiply `Math.random()` by `Math.pow(2,x)` (where `x` is a number you experiment with to find the right length) - 2^anything can always be accruately expressed by floating point numbers.
- In the `toString()`, method, insert an integer parameter that is a power of 2 (such as 8 or 16) - this will cause the number to be converted to a string with the base-8 or base-16 number system. This will prevent variable length keys and also prevent rounding.

`var pvid = cookies.get('pvid') || Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(8, 15)).toString(8);`

Comment: It makes sense, thanx. But I've ran this code 'Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 15)).toString();' for several millions of iterations and didn't get any 17 or  even 16 digits length number. How it depends on a version of browser or something like this?

Comment: There is also a stupid solution for his problem, which I guess works good enough for it's problem: `Math.random().toString().substr(2, 16)`

Comment: @nemoinho - Since that's a fundamentally different solution, you could post that as an answer rather than as a comment.